# Let p be a prime number. Prove that the equation $2/p=1/x+1/y$ has one solution with integers $0<x<y$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I wrote the equation down as $2z/pz=(y+x)/(xy)$, where z is an integer. This would create a fraction not in the most simplified version. $xy$ must have a greatest common factor $>1$ with z, since p is a prime. However, I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: If $p=2$ there are no such $x,y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in a comment above, we must have $p \neq 2.$

$2x>p, 2y>p.$ Multiply through by $2pxy$ to get $4xy-2px-2py =0,$ and
$$  (2x-p)(2y-p) = p^2  $$
with $y > x,$ we get $1 \cdot p^2 = p^2$ and $x = \frac{p+1}{2}$ and $y = \frac{p^2 + p}{2}$

Comment: For example 2/3=1/2+1/6.......+1.

Answer (score 2):

Every odd number (not just the odd primes) allows a solution :

$$\frac{2}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2n^2+3n+1}$$

Comment: This proves *at least one* solution (provided $n+1\neq 2n^2+3n+1$).

Comment: @vadim123 The question does not ask to prove that the equation has *exactly* one solution of the required form. The inequality $n+1\ne 2n^2+3n+1$ is valid for any positive $n$.